# Visual Studio 2010 IDE setting I somehow changed with keypress (Screenshot)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Does anyone know what this setting is (the dots on the lines) that I have somehow changed whilst typing in Visual Studio 2010

[image: See the dots on the lines that make it rather, busy?]

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit, Advanced, View Whitespace (Ctrl+E, S)

Comment: Saviour... :P Thanks. Will accept your answer in 6 minutes :)